# error using camel jaxb with java route

Tags: jaxb, apache-camel

According to Camel documentation, I create JaxbDataFormat (example code in documentation uses non-existing constructor, though?)

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {

    JaxbDataFormat jaxbDataFormat = new JaxbDataFormat();
    jaxbDataFormat.setContextPath("somepackage");
```

I have pom-dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-jaxb</artifactId>
        <version>2.18.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Doesn't work :  "ConvertBody... because of Data format 'jaxb' could not be created."

Could somebody please give an example code how jaxb conversions are supposed to work with Camel. I have Camel in Action 2ed, but the example there uses XML-definde route. Procedure seems simple enough with XML - but I'm not very enthusiastic about using xml as programming language ;)

Using java 8.

............

Exception in thread "CamelMainRunController" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route2 at: >>> Marshal[org.apache.camel.model.dataformat.JaxbDataFormat@57d7f108] <<< in route: Route(route2)[[From[activemq:gateway.queue]] -> [OnException... because of Data format 'jaxb' could not be created. Ensure that the data format is valid and the associated Camel component is present on the classpath
    at org.apache.camel.spring.boot.CamelSpringBootApplicationController.run(CamelSpringBootApplicationController.java:74)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.boot.CamelMainRunController$DaemonTask.run(CamelMainRunController.java:42)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route2 at: >>> Marshal[org.apache.camel.model.dataformat.JaxbDataFormat@57d7f108] <<< in route: Route(route2)[[From[activemq:gateway.queue]] -> [OnException... because of Data format 'jaxb' could not be created. Ensure that the data format is valid and the associated Camel component is present on the classpath
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:1071)
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:196)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRoute(DefaultCamelContext.java:984)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRouteDefinitions(DefaultCamelContext.java:3401)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:3132)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.access$000(DefaultCamelContext.java:183)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:2961)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:2957)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWithDefinedClassLoader(DefaultCamelContext.java:2980)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:2957)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:2924)
    at org.apache.camel.main.Main.doStart(Main.java:129)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.main.MainSupport.run(MainSupport.java:138)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.boot.CamelSpringBootApplicationController.run(CamelSpringBootApplicationController.java:69)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Data format 'jaxb' could not be created. Ensure that the data format is valid and the associated Camel component is present on the classpath
    at org.apache.camel.model.DataFormatDefinition.getDataFormat(DataFormatDefinition.java:107)
    at org.apache.camel.model.DataFormatDefinition.getDataFormat(DataFormatDefinition.java:88)
    at org.apache.camel.model.MarshalDefinition.createProcessor(MarshalDefinition.java:177)
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.makeProcessorImpl(ProcessorDefinition.java:545)
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.makeProcessor(ProcessorDefinition.java:506)
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.addRoutes(ProcessorDefinition.java:222)
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:1068)
    ... 17 more

Comment: Is `camel-jaxb` available on your classpath at runtime? How do you run Camel? Standalone? Spring? Blueprint/OSGi?

Comment: If you use spring-boot then use camel-jaxb-starter as maven dependency.

Comment: I'm using spring-boot, added camel-jaxb-starter (and restarted IDEA). Now jaxb-conversions work fine. Thanks for help !  (wonder how am I supposed to close this case ?)

Comment: @AlessandroDaRugna I have same problem. I am using Blueprint/OSGI way. In my case, if I run my bundle on fuse server then unmarshalling works well however if I test my route using Junit then I am getting error.
Not sure why is camel-jaxb not available while testing my routes. Any suggestions/idea to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user3359005 Maybe you want to open a new question for your case. Do you use this: https://camel.apache.org/blueprint-testing.html ?

Comment: @AlessandroDaRugna Yes,The link you have shared I have done as per that. Anyway, I will open a new question as you have suggested. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @catch22, could you tell me which version of Spring boot and Camel you used?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

add to pom

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-jaxb-starter</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

and update project